# Contraction semigroup on $X$ with generator $A$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

> Let $\{S(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a contraction semigroup on $X$, with generator $A$. Inductively define $D(A^k):=\{u\in D(A^{k-1}) \mid A^{k-1}u \in D(A)\}$ ($k=2,\ldots$). Show that if $u \in D(A^k)$ for some $k$, then $S(t)u \in D(A^k)$ for each $t \ge 0$.

This is from PDE Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 7, Exerise 15.

For reference, here is Theorem 1. This is on page 435 in the textbook.

> **THEOREM 1** (Differential properties of semigroups)**.** *Assume $u \in D(A)$. Then*
>
> (i) $S(t)u\in D(A)$ *for each* $t \ge 0$
>
> (ii) $AS(t)u=S(t)Au$ *for each* $t \ge 0$.
>
> (iii) *The mapping $t \mapsto S(t)u$ is differentiable for each $t>0$.*
>
> (iv) $\frac d{dt}S(t)u = AS(t)u \quad (t > 0)$.

May I receive feedback on my following proof to this problem?

My attempted proof:

If $u \in D(A^k)$, then $u \in D(A^{k-1})$ and $A^{k-1}u \in D(A)$. If $u \in D(A^{k-1})$, then $u \in D(A^{k-2})$ and $A^{k-2}u \in D(A)$. Inductively proceeding, we obtain: If $u \in D(A^2)$, then $u \in D(A)$ and $Au \in D(A)$. By parts (i) and (ii) of the theorem, $S(t)u \in D(A)$ and $AS(t)u=S(t)Au \in D(A)$, respectively; hence, $S(t)u \in D(A^2)$. Inductively proceeding back to $k$, we obtain: $S(t)u \in D(A^{k-1})$ and $A^{k-1}S(t)u \in D(A)$; hence, $S(t)u \in D(A^k)$.

Comment: What does this 'part (i) of Theorem 1' say exactly?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, basically that's it.

It might be only a typo, but using part (i) for $A^{k-1}u\in D(A)$ yields $S(t)A^{k-1}u\in D(A)$, and thus you need the exchange rule ($A^{k-1}S(t)u=S(t)A^{k-1}u$) to conclude $u\in D(A^k)$.

Note also that you implicitly used $S(t)A^{d}u\in D\left(A^{k-d}\right)$ for each $d=0\dots k$. This might need a proof.

Comment: Do you mean I should conclude actually $S(t)u \in D(A^k)$? We started from $u \in D(A^k)$.